# How to fit width columns with xlwings

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, xlwings

I wrote a function to save data in a WorkBook with [xlwings](https://www.xlwings.org/) and I want to fit the width column

```
class VehicleClass:
    def __init__(self, VehClass):
        # Vehicles 4 - Vehicle Classes
        self.VehClass = [VehClass]
        self.VehName = []
        self.ScaleFactor = []

    def add(self, VehName, ScaleFactor):
        self.VehClass*=1
        self.VehName.append(VehName)
        self.ScaleFactor.append(ScaleFactor)        

    def save(self):
        # Vehicles 4 - Vehicle Classes
        sht = wb.sheets['Vehicles 4 - Vehicle Classes']
        rng = sht.range("A1").end('down').offset(1, 0)

        for i, item in enumerate([self.VehClass, self.VehName, self.ScaleFactor]):
            rng.offset(0, i).options(transpose=True).value = item
            rng.autofit() # or rng.columns.autofit()
```

but doesn't work.

Do you have any idea ? Thank you !

Answer (score 6):

You can autofit the width of all columns in an excel file with the following code:

```
import xlwings as xw

path = r"test.xlsx"

with xw.App(visible=False) as app:
    wb = xw.Book(path)

    for ws in wb.sheets:
        ws.autofit(axis="columns")

    wb.save(path)
    wb.close()
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to take `autofit()` outside of the loop as it will auto fit the column width for each row.  Unless the last row has the longest text this won't work.

If you want to auto fit the entire column you can use `rng.entirecolumn.autofit()` or specify your range to include all rows that you want to auto fit the column width such as `sht.range("A1:A20").columns.autofit()`